# My Internet Connection Keeps Disconnecting at regular intervals

Tags: wireless-networking, internet, router, connection

I have a Cable modem connected to a router (Linksys WRT54G) 
I use internet on my Desktop PC using a Wireless Adapter (NETGEAR WG111)
I am using Windows Vista.

I tried few things like

Contacting the ISP
changing USB port for adapter
updating router firmware
tryin out the connection on a laptop
Connecting directly using a LAN cord

Nothing worked..

Anyone with more solutions ??

Comment: can you ping from the router web interface when the internet connection is not working?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, answering my own question quite late. 
but i found the answer way back.

Not much an answer but i used the older firmware of my router. and it worked great.

Answer (score 0):

your dynamic ip (or something to that effect) is being reset. My connection would disconnect every hour at the same precise time. There are a number of possible fixes, the first would be to contact your isp regarding your ip being reset so frequently. Even if your terminology is less than exact someone of general competence should understand your particular problem and forward advise on how to amend your disconnection issues.